# Spring-security remember-me, persistent token based, session registry is not getting updated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I implemented Spring security remember me using following

```
http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(lsh).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .csrf().and().rememberMe()
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
            .userDetailsService(service).tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);
    http.rememberMe().authenticationSuccessHandler(
            authenticationSuccessHandler);`
```

I can differentiate these logins in jsp by

```
<sec:authorize access="isRememberMe()">
    <h2># This user is login by "Remember Me Cookies".</h2>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize access="isFullyAuthenticated()">
    <h2># This user is login by username / password.</h2>
</sec:authorize>
```

but when a remember-me based login happens I cannot get the logged in user by

```
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
```

How can I get the details of a remember-me logged in user ?

What is difference between fully Authenticated and remember-me authenticated users ?

Comment: I have managed to fulfill my requirement by manually registering the session to the session Registry. 
 `if (sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(auth.getPrincipal(), false)
    .isEmpty()) {
   sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(req.getSession().getId(),
     auth.getPrincipal());
  }`

Is it a good approach ??